# Corrupted or Fully Damaged, DEAD SD-Card? and what to do?

Tags: sd-card, partitions

I just recently tried to play music, then suddenly music app stopped working and my phone had a hard time from not responding, I restart it and after about 4-6 minutes it came up with everything not responding!!
I then tried to format the sd-card using my computer I get message of operation not completed successfully, I tried to erase data manually, funny thing is I can erase it easily but after I reinsert the card or refresh the folder the data that I erased is there like nothing happened, I tried to do re partition it everything says succeed but after a refresh nothing change! I cannot change anything on the card. I even tried use raw data viewer and put zero in the partition table and many other places, but after a refresh partition table and everything is there no problem. I can get the data but cannot change it, anyone can say what is actually going on? is the card completely dead? or there's some hope?
It is like a readonly sdcard!!
Thanks in Advance

EDIT: Looks like boot sector at partition 1 (sector 8192) is corrupted as DriverResotre says, however it cannot fix it though, I even tried to wipe things there but nothing happened, I tried zero one using wipe disk but no go, I tried fsck too but still didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the SD-CARD went into write protect while I was listening to music, Write protect mode is happening when suddenly while reading and writing something goes wrong like lost connection to chip or getting high voltages something like that, unfortunately Sd-Card is so dead and is non-writable, you can see the data but cannot change it, if you have warranty and too much sensitive information on SD I advise not to send the card to warranty but also break the Sd card or put it in microwave for 1 or 2 second ONLY (that's what I did) as your sensitive information will be always there and someone from the warranty can access it easily and use it against you.

Hope this information become useful in future.